# applescript: do javascript fails on OSX10.8.4?

Tags: javascript, applescript

After OSX 10.8.4 update, this small script stopped working

```
tell application "Adobe Photoshop CS6"  
  do javascript "alert('hello world')"  
end tell
```

Can anyone confirm it's a change in AppleScript syntax introduced in last updated, 
or I'm missing something?

Can your reproduce this script on OSX 10.8.4?

The exact error I get is:

> Syntax error
>   Expected end of line but found identifier.

And JavaScript is highlighted.

Comment: Is it complaining about a missing semicolon? `do javascript "alert('hello world');"` Pretty crazy if it was.

Comment: no, adding semicolon does not make any difference.

Comment: It works in 10.8.4 in Illustrator. Have you tried the code by itself?

Comment: Yes, It must be something with text formatting or encoding, while copy/pasting maybe. I managed to open an already saved script, modifying it, to reproduce this snippet, and it works fine.
I can't make it fail anymore, I'm kind of frustrated/happy

Answer (score 0):

I just struggled with a similar problem in Illustrator CC on 10.8.5 for a few hours.

I was running the script through a shell command in a .sublime-build file (Sublime Text 2).

Running the same basic script once from the official AppleScript Editor subsequently fixed it.

I still need to investigate why. If you have an idea, please comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem your experiencing is due to the fact that you have to specify a tab for applescript to run the JS code in.  For example:

```
do JavaScript "alert('Hey');" in tab 1 of front window
```

If you don't specify which tab to run the javascript code in, it always throws the same 'identifier' error.

Hope this helps. (I've been frustrated by this one myself. It's easy to forget)

--Sorry, just realized you were talking about Illustrator.  My mind immediately went to Safari's 'do javascript'.